# Rename files Using the command RENAME in MS-DOS

Tags: cmd, rename

I want to know if there is any way to rename files in windows through the interpreter MS-DOS command as follows:

Suppose I have a directory with files in the following way:

```
file1.mp3
file2.mp3
file3.mp3
.
.
.
filen.mp3
```

and I want to rename as

```
author-file1.mp3
author-file2.mp3
author-file3.mp3
.
.
.
author-filen.mp3
```

where n is the number of songs and author is the same for all songs.

I read about the command to rename files in MS-DOS, more specifically RENAME but I can not create the proper syntax to do so.

I have an idea that might be something like:

> `RENAME *. mp3 author-<song_name>. mp3`

I don't know how to specify MS-DOS to place the names above each of the mp3 files so that they are as:

```
author-file1.mp3
author-file2.mp3
author-file3.mp3
.
.
.
author-filen.mp3
```

I hope someone can help me,

Comment: Don't confuse DOS with some command-interpreter in Windows. DOS is an OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for %f in (*.mp3) do rename %f author-%f
```

REF: [Microsoft Batch Help](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
ren filename new_filename
```

for example, if I want to change a filename named `hello.txt` then I will do this:

```
ren hello.txt olleh.txt
```

Comment: I think the question was about doing multiple renames, not just how to rename one file